# expo app version code error while updating on playstore

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

hi there can you please guide on how to update expo created app on play store
i have created an expo app and credentials fetch by "Let expo handle it" for first time
then after few days i have updated few things and generated new app bundle and when trying to upload on play store.
its saying version code error can you please help me with this

in very first upload i have not specified any version code
"android": {
"versionCode": 2,
"package": "app.kiocart.com"
},

but in second i am specifying but still giving version code error

Answer (score 0):

`versionCode` for android should be an **Integer** and for iOS `buildNumber` should be a **string**.